# Linkedin - Get companies updates queries

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to create an app to read company updates, but I have a few queries.  Please help...

I'm using LinkedIn api via Oauth authentication in R

1. Is there anyway to fetch more updates than the restriction (only allow fetch up to 250 updates or updates in the last 20 days whichever comes first) ?

Example code

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/270126/updates?event-type=status-update&count=100&start=0    &oauth2_access_token={access_token}
```

2. Once I got the updateKey, I'm trying to fetch the comments and likes but it's returning NO return

Example code

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/270126/updates/key=UPDATE-c270126-5951438751136768000/update-comments?event-type=status-update&oauth2_access_token={access_token}    
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/270126/updates/key=UPDATE-c270126-5951438751136768000/likes?event-type=status-update&oauth2_access_token={access_token}
```

3. From the company status-update, it's returning FALSE for is-commentable and is-likable? Is that why there are no result from Query 2. If so, is there anyway to change that setting?

'is-commentable' false '/is-commentable'

'is-likable' false '/is-likable'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Linkedin developer - Reading Company Shares link
https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares

Comment: Hi Tony,
I just took a look at your links and am unable to see the same thing you are mentioning. Are you still not seeing any comments/likes?

Comment: Same result - All I'm getting is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<update-comments/>

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *Share and Social Stream* end point instead of the *Companies* end point like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-c270126-5951438751136768000/update-comments?oauth2_access_token={access_token}
```

The documentation is here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates

Also you can test different Linkedin API calls here:
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin